# Assign values from vector to a specific part of another vector [Matlab]

Tags: matlab, vector

I am fairly new to matlab. I am sure there is a nice way to do this.

I have the vector h which contains 1257 elements.
And I have the vector t which contains 101 elements.
What I want is to assign the vector t from the 529th to the 630th element from vector h.

I tried this:
h(529:630) = t;

Then I get this message: "In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same."

If I use a scalar it works. For example:
h(529:630) = 5;

No problem there.

Can someone come up with something clever :)?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`h(529:630)` will have `630 - 529 + 1 = 102` elements

```
>> length(h(529:630))

ans =

   102
```

You must use :

```
h(530:630) = t ;
```

Or

```
h(529:629) = t ;
```

whatever the case may be.